# How to connect to a websocket API with Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, websocket

I'm trying to connect to a websocket API with Rails 5.1.4 but I don't really know where to start.

I read some tutorials and discovered that Action Cable can suit my need but all the examples are about internal use of websocket (chat, notifications etc) and not to connect to an external API.

My goal is to establish the connection / subscribe to the service and receive the feed in real time. If I can do that, I would be able to continue my project.

I am more looking for a general methodology that the detailed code for my need but I'm trying to connect to this API: https://docs.gdax.com/?ruby#websocket-feed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ActionCable is for setting up websocket *servers*. It sounds like you are looking for a websocket *client*. You could check out this gem as a starting point: https://github.com/shokai/websocket-client-simple